# Using Google Cloud Endpoints with Cloud SQL and Cloud DataStore in a polygot architecture

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-datastore

I was going through the possibility of building an universal data backend with `Google Cloud Endpoints` but because I was considering it for a business application so I needed to have `Google Cloud SQL` as my data storage and use `Google Cloud DataStore` to store configuration level data. This architecture really intrigued me to find more about the possibility of how to do this with Java but I'm astonished that there is not one single resource on the web where somebody show you how to use `Google Cloud Endpoints` with `Google Cloud SQL`, not even google has some documentation of how to achieve this. Does this mean that is impossible to achieve this in `Google Cloud` infrastructure. Can somebody point me to some resource or atleast shed some light onto this matter. Please I'd be very obliged to get some replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already use a library such as Hibernate to convert from the SQL data to Java objects, you do not have much more to do to make Cloud Endpoints work with Cloud SQL.

Simply return serializable objects when using Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Thanks David. I was thinking of using the [sql2o](http://www.sql2o.org/) library. Can u tell me if this is gonna work?

Comment: I've never tried, but there should not be any issue. The biggest issue you could have would be that the objects provided by sql2o are not correctly serializable by cloud endpoints and you would have to map them to serializable objects.

Comment: Can you elaborate. sql2o uses POJOs right, so I can annotate an Endpoint class and use those POJOs directly in the getter/setter of the endpoint methods. Whats could cause a problem?

Comment: Just test, that's the only way we'll know :-)

Comment: Thanks David. If its possible then can you share some resource. It'd be of great help.

Comment: From my experience, it seems that this approach only works in dev mode (localhost) and not in GAE infrastructure. No errors given, only empty collection is returned.